# Strange float behaviour and rogue LT symbol

Tags: css, css-float

I'm putting together http://konrad-grabowski.com and the artworks on the front page should just float one after another, however after the eight floating element, things start going wrong. I'm not sure why; could someone take a look?

Also, upon refreshing the page, sometimes a rogue less-than symbol appears to the right of my content. My guess is that this is related to the float problem, but I can't isolate the symbol in my mark up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the last three errors when you validate the page...

[W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://konrad-grabowski.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

You have open elements which should explain the random `<` or `>` symbols you're seeing.

You also have a comma at the end of this line which should be removed.  IE will probably choke on it.

```
speed: 700,
```

**EDIT:**

In my Safari web inspector, it appears that your "back to top" paragraph element is much wider than it needs to be and it's over-flowing into your gallery area pushing those images over and out of the way towards the right.

Temporarily remove your "back to top" element to see if it's the culprit and then try setting the width here instead...

```
#back-top {
    width:  108px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Comment: When I validate, I get 14 of the same error: "Bad value shadowbox[gallery] for attribute rel on element a: Keyword shadowbox[gallery] is not registered."

I suspected open elements somewhere, but I can't find them. How would I go about isolating them?

I removed the comma at the end of speed; thanks for that.

Comment: @JezenThomas:  Check out my most recent edits first.  Also, use something like Firebug or Safari's Developer's tools to inspect the DOM for things like this.  I cannot see the open tags either so I think you may be violating something else in the HTML5 spec that is causing that validation error.  Like improperly nested tags may cause various other validator errors.

Comment: @JezenThomas:  You'll have to read up on the HTML5 spec but I suspect you're not allowed to put `<section>`, `<header>`, etc. within a container `<div>`.  [Interesting Article.](http://www.expression-web-tutorial.com/Structural-Semantic-Elements.html)

Comment: Good suggestion, but that doesn't seem to be it. There was an 'a' element with `title="Adam & Eve"` but that isn't the source of the problem either. It must just be a less-than sign in there somewhere that I can't find.

Comment: I commented out a bunch of the artworks, and repeated the initial four that do work, and now the layout behaves correctly. I guess the next step is just to uncomment the other artworks one by one to try and highlight the issue.

Comment: I have fixed it! It's not a perfect fix, but it works. I added an empty `div` after every row, and used `style="clear:both;"` on them.